# Use of the word 'revile'

Tags: word-usage

I am writing a story, in which a character thinks something which in retrospect he finds absurd and paranoid, and is frustrated for having thought it in the first place.  To reflect his attitude, I want to write (in the first person):

> "Paranoid moron!" I revile.

Is this a correct usage of the word 'revile'?

Comment: Personally, I'm not a fan of this word. I prefer "loathe".

Comment: Did you do any research on the meaning of 'revile'? There are votes to close which are almost certainly due to "[lack of research](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)". If you looked it up in a dictionary, say that, which one, and why it still isn't clear.

Comment: I always like "spit" = to shoot words with venom. Really generates effective imagery! "Paranoid moron!" I spat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh, I see what you're trying to do. You're trying to use it as a more descriptive form of "said".

> "Paranoid moron!" I revile.

My apologies. Honestly, though it seems [some dictionaries](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revile) allow for this use, it's not one I've ever been familiar with.

"[Revile](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/revile)" is more commonly used as a [transitive verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_verb), which means that it **must** have a direct object.

> A transitive verb is a verb that takes one or more objects. This contrasts with intransitive verbs, which do not have objects.

You have to revile *something*.

Comment: "Moron", I revile you.  sounds pretty good.

Comment: Is changing this to ' "Paranoid Moron!" I revile myself. ' any better?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it reads well, for two reasons.

Catija already explained one; it's a transitive verb.

For another, it just doesn't seem like quite the right word.

Looking through my Mac's Dictionary app, I found an interesting usage note under the verb *scold*:

> *Revile* is reserved for very strong or even violent displays of anger. To revile is to use highly abusive and contemptuous language (: *revile one's opponent in the press*)
>
> *Chide* is a more formal term than *scold*, and it usually implies disapproval for specific failings

*Chide* could work. As a matter of fact, there's another interesting tidbit under the dictionary's entry for *chide*:

> **chide** (*verb*) `trans.`scold or rebuke : *she chided him for not replying to her letters*
> | `with direct speech` “You mustn't speak like that,” she chided gently.

It's that "with direct speech" part that I found interesting; that seems like a green light to use *chide* in the manner and construct you are using.

So, the line in your book could go like this:

> "Paranoid moron!" I chided.

but I wonder if it doesn't read a bit more naturally like this:

> I chided myself. "Paranoid moron!"

Comment: The thing is, I am trying to capture a strong, even violent, self-contempt, and chide or scold don't seem to convey that.  That's more like something a parent does to a child.

Comment: @Doug - Well, if _revile_ is the right word, just use it in a right way: _I reviled my own thoughts, and  rebuked myself. "Paranoid moron!"_

Answer (score 2):

You could write:

> I revile thee!

assuming your character had a tendency towards the theatrical type of speech.

Comment: I think is what the OP is getting at.  The object of this **transitive verb** is understood and implied.  I seems to be a good usage in that case, even without the theatrics.

Comment: This sounds weird to me.  This is something my character is thinking to himself, and I don't feel "thee" is a word many people substitute in their heads for "you" when referring to themselves.  I did suggest above ' "I revile myself" ' as a possibility.  What do you think about that?

Comment: If someone is debating with themselves (especially if they are slightly insane) it is sometimes done from the stand-point of two separate personalities (recall the scenes with Gollum in Lord of the Rings). Imagine the current self criticising the previous self. Therefore second person can be used to refer to yourself. Your character might not be insane, but he might simply be copying a theatric style. The word "revile" is somewhat archaic.

Comment: I understand that the second person can be used to refer to yourself.  The story is written mostly in first-person present tense, and I wanted to say something akin to ' "Paranoid moron" I scold ' but I wanted something stronger and more self-abusing than scold.  I think what I have learned from this post is that revile is just not the right word.